# JPA/Hibernate mapping for parent-child relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

It's a little dump question, but I must to ask.
What to do with parent-child mapping in JPA/Hibernate? Let me explain what I actually mean.

Let say, I have 2 tables - Children and Parent. Pretty straightforward mapping - bidirectional @OneToMany. I can create Children only if I have Parent and add new Children to existing Parent.
And now I need to create one more table - AnotherParent. Also my Children will have a foreigh key to new table and mapping between these tables will be @OneToOne. My question is - should I add entity mapping between these entities or I should add field 'anotherParentId' to Children class which represents assosiation between tables?

I've read Vlad Michalcea's "High performance java persistence" and haven't found any advice or solution for cases like this yet. I recognize that 'main' association here is between Children and Parent and it's important to have entity mapping for these 2 entities (from code point of view). But from ORM point of view?

```
@Entity
public class Children {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetchType = LAZY)
    private Parent parent;

    // use this?
    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private AnotherParent anotherParent;

    // or this??
    private Long anotherParentId;
}

...

@Entity
public class Parent {   
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Children> childrens = new ArrayList()<>;
}

...

@Entity
public class AnotherParent {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

Comment: If it is `@OneToOne` why do you have `@ManyToOne` in your example?

Comment: @K.Nicholas you absolutely right, I fixed that

Comment: @Zogger whether to implement a bidirectional relation or not should be business-driven. If you need it, if that makes sense conceptually, then you may implement it as a field in the class (bidi rel). Sometimes 'though, it's better not to make it a materialized relation, and use a query to retrieve children/parent if needed. I tend to limit bidi rel for cases when it adds value to the whole. Doing it blindly looks like over engineering, although this may be a subjective thematic...

Comment: @spi thanks for your reply.
Yeah, business-driven it's important, in my case a create Children entity in WEB and front-end application passes  to back-end  both parent_id and another_parent_id. Maybe of parent_id has stronger link with Children than another_parent_id then I must mapping only Parent entity

Comment: I think a `OneToOne` is not a parent but an association. I don't know of any specific guidelines for where to put the foreign key for onetoone associations. Thorben Janssen also has good advice on JPA.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128506/in-a-one-to-one-relationship-where-should-the-foreign-key-be-placed

Comment: @K.Nicholas I didn't find any advices in Thorben's blog too. About link  your attached - idk, that question is about schema structure, but I have completed schema and just try to recognize how to map my entities in best way :)

Comment: @K.Nicholas about OneToOne is not a parent - I can agree with you. But lets imagine - it is oneToMany and ManyToOne with another table. Do you have any thoughts for case like that?

Comment: The issues are unrelated.